# I can't make Restler work

Tags: php, rest, nginx

I've been trying to use the [Restler](http://luracast.com/products/restler/) php api.

I have an api.php file at the root of my webserver:

```
<?php
require_once('lib/restler.php');

class Say {
    function hello($to='world') {
        return "Hello $to!";
    }
}

$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('Say');
$r->handle();
?>
```

I try with the simplest example GET api.php/say/hello, but nginx keep responding me with an error 404. And in the logs I see "Not a directory".

I guess it's a problem with my nginx conf, but can't find any specific information about it. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve my problem:

I put my code into /api/index.php

Then modified my nginx configuration to add:

```
location /api {
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /api/index.php last;
        }

        if (!-d $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /api/index.php last;
        }
    }
```

So now if I call GET /api/say/hello, it redirects to /api/index.php/say/hello and the rewriting rules allow restler to do its magic.

I hope this will help future users of restler on nginx.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [rewrite module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) to see how you can make nginx accept `api.php/say/hello` URLs.

Answer (score 0):

After former consideration and even though the solution works, according to nginx documentation - (IfIsEvil http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) - you should be able to do this without the if as follows:

```
location /api {
    try_files $uri /api/index.php;

    #if (!-f $request_filename) {
    #    rewrite ^(.*)$ /api/index.php last;
    #}

    #if (!-d $request_filename) {
    #    rewrite ^(.*)$ /api/index.php last;
    #}
}
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: That will not work with GET calls, it has to be like this "try files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php?$args".